# Java: Immutability of Composite Objects

Tags: java

Suppose I've an Employee class with below definition:

```
class Employee {
   private final String id;
   private final String name;
   private final String dept;
   private final Address address;

   public Employee(String id, String name, String dept, Address address) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.dept = dept;
    this.address = address;
   }

  public String getId() {
    return id; 
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name; 
  }

  public String getDept() {
    return dept; 
  }

  public Address getAddress() {
    return address; 
  }
}

class Address {
  private String addrLine1;
  private String addrLine2;
  ...
}
```

In above code, is Employee really immutable given that Address object can be changed with setters? If not, should we clone() Employee to return original Employee?...

Comment: Your code is incorrect. Your attribute Address is declared as a String but your getter returns an Address. And btw, that's not a question you are asking.

Comment: Given that they're key to your question, why in heaven's name did you leave the setters out of the quoted code?!

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: Quite true about the Address thing, but surely that bit at the bottom is pretty clearly a question?

Comment: There's a second issue here in that `Employee` is subclassable, so an instance could be made mutable even if `Address` wasn't.

Comment: @TJ sorry, I did not understand the question because it seems to me that it is quite obvious that if an attribute of an object is mutable, then your object is also mutable. Won't do it again, promise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone() the mutable object which is Address.  cloning Employee won't help.

Answer (score 5):

If your `Address` class has setters that make it mutable, then no, I would say `Employee` is not immutable because the address it contains can change.

Answer (score 1):

If its state is mutable, **it's not immutable!** If the returned object is mutable, the first object reference data will change too.

As you said, just return a safe-copy.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that any mutable fields are cloned before storing them, and cloned when being returned in a getter.
In your constructor:

```
    this.address = address.clone();
```

and in your getter:

```
    return address.clone();
```

This way noone else but this Employee object has access to the location of the adress object.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want in immutability:  If you want it to mean that the *entire graph* of the object isn't going to change, then obviously, having a mutable address isn't going to achieve this.

You could term this 'deep' immutability as opposed to 'shallow' immutability I guess.

[Pure4J](https://github.com/robmoffat/pure4j) provides an `@ImmutableValue` annotation (and associated maven plugin to compile-time check your code) to ensure that when you want something to be deep-immutable, it actually is.

*Disclaimer:  I'm the developer of this library*

But, I hope it's useful to someone.